# Getting nested values with XML reader in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have a problem where I am trying to get the values of my nested elements in my XML file.

```
-<Modules>
 -<Modules4>
   -<Module>
       <Name>dasd</Name>
       <Code>dasdasdas</Code>
       <Credits>40</Credits>
    </Module>
   -<Module>
     <Name>dasdasd</Name>
     <Code>dasdasd</Code>
     <Credits>40</Credits>
   </Module>
</Modules4>

 <Modules5/>

 <Modules6/>

 </Modules>
```

This is the XML file, i am trying to create a condition where if the reader finds the "Modules4" Element, then get the nested elements "Name", "Code" and "Credits" if this question has been answered, please direct me to it as I can not find it anywhere.

```
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("SavedData.xml"))
            while (reader.Read())
        {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "Modules4"){

                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "Name":
                            string name = reader.ReadString();
                            Console.WriteLine(name);
                            break;

                        case "Code":
                            string Code = reader.ReadString();
                            Console.WriteLine(Code);
                            break;

                        case "Credits":

                            break;


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code.

Thanks.

Comment: First, are you sure you need an XmlReader (ie your data is ~ 1GB or more) ?  Because this is so much easier with XElement.

Comment: I've never used it, just thought XmlReader was easier.

Comment: You thought very wrong. Do look at System.Xml.Linq;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that the `switch` is only reached when `reader.Name` *is* `"Modules4"`, never one of its children.

If I were you I'd use the `ReadSubtree()` method:

```
...
if (reader.IsStartElement())
{
    if (reader.Name == "Modules4") 
    {
        ReadModules4(reader.ReadSubtree());
    }
}
...
```

Then you can process the subtree in a separate method:

```
void ReadModules4(XmlReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.Name)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using combination of xml reader and xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            reader.ReadToFollowing("Modules4");
            XmlReader module4Subtree = reader.ReadSubtree();
            while (!module4Subtree.EOF)
            {
                if (module4Subtree.Name != "Module")
                {
                    module4Subtree.ReadToFollowing("Module");
                }
                if (!module4Subtree.EOF)
                {
                    XElement module = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(module4Subtree);
                    Module.modules.Add(new Module() { name = (string)module.Element("Name"), code = (string)module.Element("Code"), credits = (int)module.Element("Credits") });
                }

            }
        }
    }
    public class Module
    {
        public static List<Module> modules = new List<Module>();

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public int credits { get; set; }
    }
}
```